# How to format print outputs of a text file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a text file called animal.txt.

```
1.1  Animal Name  : Dog
     Animal Type  : Mammal
     Fur          : Yes
     Scale        : No

1.2  Animal Name  : Snake
     Animal Type  : Reptile
     Fur          : No
     Scale        : Yes

1.3  Animal Name  : Frog
     Animal Type  : Amphibian
     Fur          : No
     Scale        : No

1.x  Animal Name  : aaaaaa
     Animal Type  : bbbbbb
     Fur          : cccccc
     Scale        : dddddd
```

My desired ouput is:

```
Dog     Mammal      Yes
Snake   Reptile     No
Frog    Amphibian   No
```

Output I am getting is:

```
Dog Mammal Yes
Snake Reptile No
Frog Amphibian No
```

This is the code I currently have that prints out my current input.

```
with open('animal.txt', 'r') as fp:
for line in fp:
    header = line.split(':')[0]
    if 'Animal Name' in header:
        animal_name = line.split(':')[1].strip()
        print animal_name,
    elif 'Animal Type' in header:
        animal_type = line.split(':')[1].strip()
        print animal_type,
    elif 'Fur' in header:
        fur = line.split(':')[1].strip()
        print fur
    elif '1.x' in header:
        break
```

Is there a way to format or add to my existing code that will give me my desired output?

Answer (score -1):

Use `\t` between the items you are printing. So print `animal_name\t,` then so on through the rest of your code.

`with open('animal.txt', 'r') as fp:
for line in fp:
    header = line.split(':')[0]
    if 'Animal Name' in header:
        animal_name = line.split(':')[1].strip()
        print animal_name\t,
    elif 'Animal Type' in header:
        animal_type = line.split(':')[1].strip()
        print animal_type\t,
    elif 'Fur' in header:
        fur = line.split(':')[1].strip()
        print fur\t
    elif '1.x' in header:
        break`

Comment: tried it but it doesn't work. gives me this message>>> SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character

Comment: Sorry, Try putting the `'\t'` put the quotes in there. That should fix that issue.

Comment: Like so?.-----> print animal_name'\t'

Comment: Yes, just like that

Comment: it still doesn't work. says invalid syntax :(

Comment: I'll make the text file and try helping you out. Give me a little bit :)

Comment: ok thank you :) really appreciate it

Comment: Oh, you need animal_name + '\t'.. But I just saw that you will still have a bit of an issue with the formatting.

Comment: It works for now. i see what you mean by having issues with formatting still. but thank you anyways :)